# Codeigniter - link

Tags: php, codeigniter

i try to do login pages with session in Codeigniter.

In order to do that ,  i made a model

```
function girisKontrol($username, $password) {
        $sha1_password = sha1($password);
        $query = "SELECT id FROM pasaj_register WHERE username = ? and password = ?";

        $result = $this->db->query($query, array($username, $sha1_password));

        if ($result->num_rows() == 1)
            return $result->row(0)->id;
        else
            return false;
    }
```

and in giris controller i made a function called giris

```
 public function giris() {

        extract($_POST);


        $userID = $this->giris->girisKontrol($username,$password);
        echo $userID;

        if (!$userID) {

            $this->session->set_flashdata('login error',TRUE);

            redirect('giris/giris');

        } else {
            $this->session->set_userdata(array(
                    'logged_in' => TRUE,
                    'userID' => $userID));

            redirect('welcome_message');
        }


}
```

in the same controller i made one function more:

```
public function main_page()
    {
        if ($this->session->userdata('logged_in'))
            echo "Logged in";
        else
            echo "Error";


    }
```

and use all of these in view

```
 <form method="POST" action="http://localhost:81/pasaj/giris/main_page/" name="flogin" autocomplete="off">

        <label for="username"><b>Kullanıcı adı</b> ya da <b>e-posta</b> adresiniz:</label>
        <input type="text" value="" class="normalinput" name="username" id="username">
        <label for="password">Şifreniz:</label>
        <input type="password" class="normalinput" value="" name="password" id="password">
        <span class="bigsubmitwbtn yellow fright"><span class="bigsubmitwbtn_left"></span><input type="submit" class="bigbutton" name="submit" value="Giriş"></span>
        </form>
    </div>
```

However as declered in main_page function , it goes directly else statement and prints Error Why ?

Comment: Have you tried declaring and fetching an other session value? I'm not fully sure, but maybe sessions aren't proberly saved due to server being on localhost (your computer)?

Comment: Do you store your data in database or not? What is var_dump of your session?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try loading session e.g. in autoload.php in your aaplication/config folder:

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('session');
```

or in constructor of your controller.

Also make sure that session is set correctly in your config.php like:

```
$config['sess_cookie_name']     = 'cisession';
$config['sess_expiration']      = 86400;
$config['sess_expire_on_close'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_encrypt_cookie']  = FALSE;
$config['sess_use_database']    = FALSE;
$config['sess_table_name']      = 'ci_sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip']        = FALSE;
$config['sess_match_useragent'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_time_to_update']  = 300;
```

And as mentioned change $config['sess_cookie_name'] from:

```
$config['sess_cookie_name']     = 'ci_session';
```

to:

```
$config['sess_cookie_name']     = 'cisession';
```

Also is your session set correctly e.g:

```
// create session
$this->session->set_userdata($data);
```

How do store session data? In database or not?

Answer (score 0):

In codeigniter config have changed the default session/cookie names and domains?

Make sure you change the name including a underscore "_" since underscore doesnt work in all browsers, for example IE ;)